# iOS app force landscape on tablets, force portrait on phones with same build

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, ipad

I have a Swift iOS app which runs on all phones and tablets.
I want to use the same codebase and IPA file for all devices.
On phones the app should be portait.
On tablets the app should be landscape.

I can get it to not allow rotation if you are in the correct orientation, but if you launch the app when the device is in the wrong orientation, it will start off the app in the wrong orientation and force you to physically rotate the phone to fix it, and even then the screen is messed up.

In the General:Deployment Info:Device Orientation: I have both Portrait and Landscape checked

note this is similar to other questions already asked but I can't find my special situation.

I am using this code in all View Controllers to prevent rotation if you are already in the correct orientation:

```
    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool
{
    let orientation:UIDeviceOrientation = UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation

    print(orientation)

    if(UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone)
    {
        if(orientation.isLandscape)
        {
            return true
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(orientation.isPortrait)
        {
            return true
        }

    }

    return false
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask
{
    if(UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone)
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
    }
    else
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code I use that will change the orientation to the orientation that I want the VC in.

Frist I have this struct.

```
struct Device {

// MARK: - Singletons

static var TheCurrentDevice: UIDevice {
    struct Singleton {
        static let device = UIDevice.currentDevice()
    }
    return Singleton.device
}


static var TheCurrentDeviceHeight: CGFloat {
    struct Singleton {
        static let height = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height
    }
    return Singleton.height
}

// MARK: - Device Idiom Checks

static var PHONE_OR_PAD: String {
    if isPhone() {
        return "iPhone"
    } else if isPad() {
        return "iPad"
    }
    return "Not iPhone nor iPad"
}

static var DEBUG_OR_RELEASE: String {
    #if DEBUG
        return "Debug"
    #else
        return "Release"
    #endif
}

static var SIMULATOR_OR_DEVICE: String {
    #if (arch(i386) || arch(x86_64)) && os(iOS)
        return "Simulator"
    #else
        return "Device"
    #endif
}



static func isPhone() -> Bool {
    return TheCurrentDevice.userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone
}

static func isPad() -> Bool {
    return TheCurrentDevice.userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad
}

static func isDebug() -> Bool {
    return DEBUG_OR_RELEASE == "Debug"
}

static func isRelease() -> Bool {
    return DEBUG_OR_RELEASE == "Release"
}

static func isSimulator() -> Bool {
    return SIMULATOR_OR_DEVICE == "Simulator"
}

static func isDevice() -> Bool {
    return SIMULATOR_OR_DEVICE == "Device"
 }


}
```

Then in the VC veiwdidload that I want to control I use this code.

```
    override func viewDidload() {
        let CD = Device.PHONE_OR_PAD
        if CD == "iPhone" {
           let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
           UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
           shouldAutorotate()
       }
   }

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    switch UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation {
    case .Portrait, .PortraitUpsideDown, .Unknown:
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 10):

easy way is to remove the constraint in plist which is not required as shown in the image,,, i wanted the ipad to only show the potrait version of the app as it looks in iphone so i only kept portrait (bottom home button[image])

Comment: Great, difficult to find, but it's so earsy and work fine. In the plist, go to the TARGET, then Info tab, and finally in the Custom IOS target properties list.